# Accessing Route Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller called 'PersonController' and an action called 'GetNameFromId' that takes a parameter called 'userId'. I use a route attribute
on the action as below.

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    [Route("Get-Name/{userId}")]
    public ActionResult GetNameFromId(string userId)
    {
        var id = this.userService.GetName(userId);

        return View(id);
    }
}
```

In the constructors initialization i would like to access the 'userId' value - i have been looking through the requestContext object passed to the controllers Initialize override, however in QuickWatch i cannot find any suitable way to find 'userId'

This is a simplified version of the controller, but i can guarantee ever action will have the 'userId' parameter, and all actions will specify it as part of the route

How can i get access to this value before the action itself fires?

Comment: are you always passing a new userId to your actions? If not, you intialise it in the constructor and call the private field variable in your actions.

Comment: @SHammelburg whilst you didnt actually answer the question, you did pose a comment that made me realise i was being stupid. So in a round-about way - thanks!